# MVC Delete not hitting HttpPost Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, http-post, http-get

I'm using MVC3. I learned that its a bad practice to delete an item using HttpGet Method as any one can browse to the url and deletes an item. So I want to perform delete operation on HttpPost Method.

The problem is that when I click delete button, it gets hit on HttpGet method only but not on HttpPost method.

I've used webgrid and its the index.cshtml file

```
<div id="DataTable">
@grid.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new {id="gvMovies" },
columns:grid.Columns(
grid.Column("Title","Movie Title",canSort:true),
grid.Column("Director","Film Maker",canSort:false),   
grid.Column(header:"Action",
format:@<text>
<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Movies", new { id = @item.Id })">Edit</a>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Movies", new { id = @item.id }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = @item.id }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this article?');" })
}

</text>)))
</div>
```

The controller page is as follows

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually it's not correct to use the POST verb for delete. POST - is intended for posting information. The correct way would be to to just remove the attribute from the Delete method, and let it go with the GET verb.

Now if you really really really need to use the POST, your first mistake is that you create a link, instead of a submit button that will submit the form. Replace

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "De...
```

with:

```
  <input type="submit" value="Delete">
```

Comment: If possible kindly go through this link [Delete Links Creates Security Holes](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2009/01/21/asp-net-mvc-tip-46-ndash-donrsquot-use-delete-links-because) and you could know why i hates performing delete using HttpGet Method

Comment: I can understand your concern, but I must say the proposed solution doesn't seem right. What the author of the post is saying is that not only the delete, but any Get operation that changes data is vulnerable. I'd rather create security attributes that would verify a set of security rules on actions that might otherwise be vulnerable. The rules could be: the refferal and the requested content type.

Answer (score 0):

you must add submit button instead of link so you must change
`@Html.ActionLink("Delete"` to `<input type=submit value="del" >`

if you want send id in the post you can add hidden input in the form so you can add some thing like this before  your submit button in the form

```
<input type="hidden" value=@item.Id name="itemid" >
```

so i think this code will work

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Movies", new { id = @item.id }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

    {
       <input type="hidden" value=@item.Id name="itemid" >
      <input type=submit value="del" >
    }
```